# php/mysqli only half of table being populated when using a counter and hyperlink

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using mysqli and php to fill the rows of a table using the following while loop. I am wanting to make the values of the second column (always just the second column) a hyperlink to another page.

```
    // Print rows of table
     while($row = $data->fetch_row()) {
        echo "<tr>";
        $i = 0;
        foreach($row as $cell) {
           if($i == 1) {
              echo "<td> <a href='detailed.php?serial=" .$cell. "</a>$cell</td>";

           }
          else{
             echo "<td>$cell</td>";
          }
          $i++;
        }
       echo "</tr>";
     }
```

The issue with this code is that when I increment the i counter, only the odd rows of my table are displayed. When I comment out the increment, the table displays correctly (sans hyperlink). Does anyone have any insight as to why this may be and what could be done to correct it? Or any other suggestions as to how this could be accomplished?

Thanks for your time and help

Comment: `echo "<td> <a href='detailed.php?serial=" .$cell. "</a>$cell</td>";` your anchor tag is not properly arranged

Comment: Try changing

`echo "<td> <a href='detailed.php?serial=" .$cell. "</a>$cell</td>";`

to

`echo "<td> <a href='detailed.php?serial=" .$cell. ">$cell</a></td>";`

Comment: use this `echo "<td><a href='detailed.php?serial={$cell}'>{$cell}</a></td>";`

Comment: yeah, you have a quote missing there; look at your HTML source.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, jumped to conclusions to quickly. @ScottSmudger is completely right there. 
The line in the if should be

```
echo "<td> <a href='detailed.php?serial=" .$cell. "'>$cell</a></td>";
```

Old:

```
echo "<td>". $cell ."</td>"
```

Maybe?

Comment: the dots don't make a difference. You have enough rep right now to have made this a comment instead. Edit: This comment as per original post http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43506779/1

Comment: In addition, typos should be flagged for closure, not answered (and certainly not upvoted.)

Comment: I noticed you got a downvote; I can honestly say that it isn't mine.

Comment: @Fred-ii- No problem. I hope the answer is right now and somebody makes up their mind about that downvote.

Comment: That did it, just missing a ' after $cell. Thanks for being my fresh eyes